# Getting Error in Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query written below. i am getting

> Column 'JDT1.Debit' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

error when i try to run this . please have look on query written below

```
SELECT T3.[AcctName],
       SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget, sum(T0.[DebRLTotal]/85) as 'Current Expenses',T4.[Debit]
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode],[Project]
    from OACT AS T1
    ) as T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] INNER JOIN JDT1 T4 ON T3.[AcctCode] = T4.[Account] INNER JOIN OASC T5 ON T3.[Project]=T5.[Code]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T3.[AcctName],T2.[Name]
```

Comment: What is it about the error message that you don't understand?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T4.[Debit] is not in your group by clause. Since there is no aggregate function surrounding T4.[Debit], you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `T4.[Debit]` in `group by` clause or remove it from `select` clause . Because Avoiding unaggregated columns in `group by` leads to indeterminate behaviour.

For more information : [Why Must That Column Be Contained in an Aggregate Function or the GROUP BY clause?](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/07/20/but-why-must-that-column-be-contained-in-an-aggregate.aspx)

```
SELECT T3.[AcctName], SUM(T0.[DebLTotal]/85) AS buget, 
       sum(T0.[DebRLTotal]/85) as 'Current Expenses',T4.[Debit]
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Salaries%' THEN 'Salaries'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Travel%' THEN 'Travel'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Supplies%' THEN 'Supplies'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Consultants%' THEN 'Consultants'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Patient%' THEN 'Patient Care'
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Equipment%' THEN 'Equipments' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Expense%' THEN 'Other Expenses' 
                WHEN T1.[AcctName] LIKE '%Alteration%' THEN 'Alterations/Renovations'
                ELSE 'Alterations/Renovations'
           END as [AcctName],
           [AcctCode],[Project]
    from OACT AS T1
    ) as T3 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T3.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] 
INNER JOIN JDT1 T4 ON T3.[AcctCode] = T4.[Account] 
INNER JOIN OASC T5 ON T3.[Project]=T5.[Code]
where T2.[Name] = 'Main Budget 2015'
GROUP BY T3.[AcctName],T2.[Name],T4.[Debit]
```